# Getting error on compiling and installing kernel?

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, kernel

When I run make modules_install after compiling the linux kernel it gives me the following error message.

```
root@momersaleem:/usr/src/linux-3.14# make modules_install
  INSTALL arch/x86/crypto/aes-i586.ko
./signing_key.x509 at /usr/src/linux-3.14/scripts/sign-file line 56.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/crypto/aes-i586.ko] Error 255
make: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
```

Please suggest what to do?

Thanks,
momersaleem

Comment: What kind of kernel did you try to install (version, source) on which system? (Gentoo, Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat...)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar error when installing a 3.17 kernel on top of RHEL7.1. All I did was to disable CONFIG_MODULE_SIG and CONFIG_ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE in kernel config. If you dont need this feature, you can do the same, and I hope it will work.